# Problem when adding a third line to subplot

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

I need to create subplots that represents 3 variables (line plots) in each one, but the problem is that when i add the third one, the subplot goes wrong (the line is displayed wrong). This doesnt happen when i include only x and two variables.

In this example, the first subplot is ok with the variables x , y1 y2, but when i add y3 it goes wrong. x, y1, y2, and y3 are columns of a data frame where x is 01, 02, 03 and 04 and the others are values for those months. Thanks

```
# Subplot 1
#axis[0, 0].plot(x, y1, y2, y3) #WORKS WRONG WHEN ADDING Y3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to repeat the `x` in the call to `plot`:

```
ax.plot(x, y1, x, y2, x, y3)
```

or repeatedly call `plot` on the same axes object:

```
for y in (y1, y2, y3):
    ax.plot(x, y)
```

See **Plotting multiple sets of data** in the docs for [`plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html).